# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager. No fix?

Tags: react-native

I have followed the guide on the react-native-maps documentation : I got the error.

I looked everywhere on stackoverflow and on google and I was not able to find a fix.

I tried all answers I could find on forums and I still get the error.

**The error :**

*Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "AIRMap" was not found in the UIManager.*

**My code :**

```
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
         style = {styles.map}
         showsUserLocation = {false}
         followUserLocation = {false}
         zoomEnabled = {true}
      />
   )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
  map: {
     height: 400,
     marginTop: 80
  }
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to run on iOS, Android or both?

Comment: For the moment I only tried on iOS

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  How did you link 'react-native-maps'? If you used `react-native link react-native-maps` with npm, make sure you installed it with the `--save` tag.

Comment: I used `react-native link react-native-maps`. But I used yarn, so I don't need to add `--save` right ?

Comment: That's how it is supposed to work, but the docs only mention yarn in context  of running the post install script.

Comment: Anything new on this? Did you manage to fix the issue @jeanjohny ?

Comment: getting the same issue on android. Did anyone solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by only running react-native run-android.
**Note:** if you have run react-native link unlink this first.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add google api key in your project as well to install the library properly.

Answer (score 1):

If this helps someone in the future.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md), it says you need to paste the below code above `use_native_modules!`

pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils', :git => 'https://github.com/Simon-TechForm/google-maps-ios-utils.git', :branch => 'feat/support-apple-silicon'

rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path

But I had pasted mine above `config = use_native_modules!` instead of above `use_react_native!`.

Be aware of this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

open xcode project > your project > Build Phases > Link Binaries > Remove libAirMaps.a > 
 then add it again > check if it works ... 
[check image for detailed instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhGAw.png)

Edit :
if you already installed react-native-maps try to add AirMapsLib manually. Follow the instructions on this image. after that, try again the above instruction.
[image: image instruction 1 here!]

[image: image instruction 2 here!]

Comment: Unfortunately I can not find libAirMaps.a
It is not in the listing and when I try to add it, xcode does not find it

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So to do it the best I way I have to follow the instructions of the official documentation (using `react-native link react-native-maps`) and then I follow the images of your updated answer ?

Comment: Still getting the issue…

Answer (score 0):

Please check these two links which provide you detailed information about react native map integration in iOS & Android

[Map integration link 1 for Android & ios](https://medium.com/@juanli_dev/install-react-native-maps-bccae45b6083)

[Map integration link 2](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-integrate-maps-in-react-native-using-react-native-maps-5745490fe055)

Some time iOS library does not link properly so you need to manually add library into Xcode.

Comment: Still getting the issue following the two tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I do not face this issue yet in iOS but on Android. 
`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent:xxx not found in UIManager`

Issue seems to be the dependent is not linked to your project, hence 2 solutions for this issue (depending on your 'dependency')

1. run `react-native link` in terminal/cmd at your project path.
2. Manual append the dependency in your MainApplication.java as shown below:

Manual append the dependency in your MainApplication.java as shown below:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {      

      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for 
      packages.add(new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage());
      packages.add(new xxxPackage());
    }
```

There may be

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to MainApplication.java

```
import com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage; 




        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          packages.add(new MapsPackage());
          return packages;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of `yarn`. As npm would give giving errors that has no relevance to the solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

for me i had on my ios map, i had to close my terminal and my stimulator then restart again and everything was okay.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are **2 possible errors** which throw AIRMap error in your application.

1. Check your **GOOGLE GEO API KEY** is set correctly in AndroidManifest.xml. For e.g.:

`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"> <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/> </application>`

2. **react-native-maps package** is out of date.
   With "react-native-maps": "^0.25.0" i had this problem too.
   So try to update **react-native-maps** package. In your package.json set for e.g. `"react-native-maps": "^1.4.0"`